# I was leaning the bike against the wall

Tags: brakes, caliper

[image: this is the part that i hit against the radiator in the right side of the picture]I have a quite a new bike (aluminium frame) and I came home after a ride and when I was leaning a bike against the wall I hit the brake caliper (or more like the tube, that's next to it) against the wall. It was not with much of a force but I'm little bit scared if I didn't damage the brake or the caliper.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE.  There are several similar questions on this subject on this site, worth investigating to see if it answers your question. Additionally, without some pictures/images there is no way to answer your question reliably.  Are we talking about a small blemish, or are the tubes of your bike frame bent?  Pictures, detailed please.  Edit your question to add them.

Answer (score 6):

The bike must be able to handle such usage. And much worse. What can happen with some moderate force is moving the caliper very slightly out of alignment. Then it must be re-aligned. Out of alignment would show itself as brake rub. Bigger forces could cause it to move more and potentially deform the rotor, but that must already be some force.

If you lean the bike on the wall by the rotor itself than it could potentially be deformed. Maybe not always just by the weight of the bike itself, but I would be worried even about that. With some additional force it is certainly possible.  Try not to do that. The rotor could also become contaminated by touching other stuff.

The frame tubes must be able to withstand some beating and small falls. Otherwise the bike would be plain dangerous if it were too fragile.

Answer (score 2):

Worst-case scenario, you bumped a brake component out of alignment and the only symptom will be that you hear the brake disc rubbing (in which case, have a qualified mechanic inspect the brake and replace the disc if the disc is bent). It is extremely unlikely that you did any damage that poses a safety issue when leaning the bike against a wall.

Answer (score 1):

The disc brake rotor and the brake cable+housing are the most fragile parts back there. The frame tubes and the caliper should be quite strong, especially close to the rear axle.

As long as the rotor is not bent to the point where it rubs and the brake cable housing doesn’t have any (deep) scratches or kinks I wouldn’t worry at all.

When the bike falls over or is leaned against a flat surface the fragile parts should be protected by the frame and wheel. They are only really at risk when you hit uneven objects (e.g. falling on a small boulder).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the seat/chain stay touched the wall rather than the caliper. If it was a *controlled lean* - as you say there was not much force involved - and no damage (scratches, dents) or damage symptoms (brakes scratching) are present, I don't think there is a problem. Even a light scratch in the paint doesn't mean your bike is a write-off, it's just the first scratch that hurts the most.

As explained in other answers, frames can take more than that - aluminum would bend or show visible dents, then the part may be weakened, on carbon bikes a chip of one or more carbon layers or cracks would be problematic.

This [question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/90339/small-dents-on-bicycle-frame) (or [this](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/71566/how-is-this-damaged-aluminium-frame-likely-to-fail?rq=1) one) give some reference about actual aluminum frame damage in various levels from cosmetic to "beyond repair"/failed.

Just make sure that you lean your bike against a wall with parts don't take any damage from touching metal/concrete and the bike isn't likely to fall over the way you park it. So, it shouldn't be able to roll and at an angle towards the wall. Also consider wind, I once parked my bike on a mountain summit and the wind blew it over for a fall.

That's a good video on the topic, no need to copy and paste content from there: